# Communication between actions in Applicative style

Tags: haskell, ghci, applicative

Haskell design patterns, writes this example:

```
(+) <$> Nothing <*> Just 10 <*> Just 20
```

to justify that there is limited communication between actions in Applicative style.

The problem is I do not get this example to compile in ghci, with error:

```
<interactive>:28:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a b. (Num (a -> b), Num a) => Maybe b
```

Comment: Put briefly, this fails for essentially the same reason that `(+) 0 10 20` would fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example is wrong. Any of these work:

```
Prelude> (+) <$> Nothing <*> Just 10
Nothing
Prelude> (+) <$> Just 10 <*> Just 20
Just 30
Prelude> (+) <$> Just 20 <*> Nothing
Nothing
```

but the one given doesn't, because `(+)` has only two arguments.

Using it as `(+)<$>_<*>_<*>_` means the compiler tries to infer a type in which `(+)` has three arguments. Well, that's not completely inconceivable since Haskell multi-argument functions really are functions of an argument yielding a function of another argument yielding...
So, a “two-argument function” `a -> a -> a` *can* in principle have more arguments if you instantiate `a` itself with a function type. Say, `a ~ (Int -> Int)`, then

```
(+) :: Num (Int -> Int) => (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
                           ┗━━━━━━━━━━┛    ┗━━━━━━━━━━┛    ┗━┛
```

Voilà, three arguments. The problem is that `Int -> Int` or more generally `a->b` is *not* a numerical type, i.e. `Num (a -> b)` is not a constraint that can be fulfilled, though somebody conceivable *could* write such an instance.

Note that sometimes, constraints as `Monoid (a,b)` *can* make sense, and GHC does allow them, but you'll need to follow the advice and enable the `FlexibleContexts` extension by either putting `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` on top of your source file, or `:set -XFlexibleContexts` in GHCi. In your example, that doesn't help at all though.

To apply `(+)` to an arbitrary number or arguments, you can fold it over a list:

```
> :m +Data.List
> foldl1 (+) [0,10,20]
30
```

Likewise, you can fold the applicative-lifted form (`liftA2 (+) p q ≡ (+)<$>p<*>q`) over a list of Maybe-numbers:

```
> :m +Control.Applicative
> foldl1 (liftA2(+)) [Nothing, Just 10, Just 20]
Nothing
> foldl1 (liftA2(+)) [Just 0, Just 10, Just 20]
Just 30
```